# Reflection Principle and Random Walks

Tags: probability

What does the reflection principle say about $P_a(S_n \geq i, T> n)$, for $a> 0$ and $i, n \geq 0$. Here $a$ is the starting point of the random walk, $S_n$ is the $n$th step of the walk, and $T$ is the first time the walk reaches $0$.

I'm not sure where my reflection point reference should be. Some hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $S_n=i>0$, denote the total number of paths from $S_0=a$ to $S_n=i$ as $N_{a,i}=\Big(^{n}_{\frac{n+i-a}{2}}\Big)$, then total number of paths from $S_0=a$ to $S_n=i$ without $S_k=0$ for any $k\leq n$ is $N_{a,i}-N_{-a,i}$, so
$$2^nP(S_n\geq i,T>n)=\sum_{k=i}^{n+a}(N_{a,k}-N_{-a,k})$$